# Где может содержаться элемент style

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, style

В [спецификации html5 написано](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element)

> Contexts in which this element can be used: Where metadata content is
>   expected.

Примерный перевод: элемент `<style>` может содержаться там, где предполагается содержимое метаданных. А где (в каких элементах) предполагается это содержимое метаданных? Я думаю вряд ли имеется ввиду в элементах содержимого метаданных (base link meta noscript script style template title), а то как-то не логично.

А в конце спецификации https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1 по-моему еще большая путаница. Там, где может содержаться элемент style  отмечены следующие элементы: head; noscript*; flow* . Про noscript понятно - "In a noscript element that is a child of a head element." А вот откуда там взялись flow и head? Почему такая разница в описании элемента и сводной таблице в конце спецификации?

Т.е. совсем непонятно, в каких элементах все-таки может содержаться элемент `<style>`?

Comment: Вы бы привели ссылку в документе, где вам первая фраза встретилась, чтобы не гадать о контексте, хорошо?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае речь идёт не о разделе `<head></head>` html-документа, а о разделении двух слоёв документа: разметки логической (по сути html - это plain текст, в котором есть указания "вот тут начинается логический заголовок", "вот тут начинается список" и т.п.) и разметки стилевой ("этот заголовок нужно отрисовать шрифтом Verdana размером 16 пикселей").

И, если воспринимать так: есть контент, есть html-теги - это данные, то стилевая разметка -- это как раз и есть метаданные (то есть "данные для данных").

Посмотрите по приведённой ссылке определение метаданных (Metadata content) это как раз "...is content that sets up the presentation or behavior of the rest of the content, or ..."

Ваш вопрос не совсем точен:

> Т.е. совсем непонятно, в каких элементах все-таки может содержаться
>   элемент `<style>`?

Более корректно спросить

> В каких частях html-документа может содержаться элемент style?

и ответ из спецификации -- "в тех, где потребуются метаданные о стилевой разметке".

Comment: Я про элемент style, а не атрибут

Comment: Действительно. И это было мельком упомянуто в вопросе, я не обратил внимания - а вот по приведённой ссылке сразу понятно. Ответ я подредактирую, но смысл не сильно поменяется. Посмотрите по ссылке определение что такое метаданные (Metadata content ) -- это "...is content that sets up the presentation or behavior of the rest of the content, or ...."

Comment: А какие это теги, я так и не понял? В каких тегах может присутствовать тег <style>?